# Variable dropdown in Forms not accepting inputs after its source range changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

We have a spreadsheet that tracks agents that is shared by multiple people. I have a dropdown that filters the agents based by team so that managers can see their team easier. I have a form linked to that spreadsheet with a dropdown that updates based on that filter. So when a user selects their team they can open the form and only see their team on it, just like on the spreadsheet.

Once the form is open, the dropdown menu is set correctly, even if another user changes the filter afterwards. The problem is when the first user submits the form the agent field returns blank if the filter has changed. My guess is that forms is doing some sort of hidden validation and since the first form's entry no longer matches the filtered list it rejects the input.

Example: User 1 selects their name and the sheet is filtered to show agents 1, 2, 3, and 4. User 1 opens the form and the dropdown there only includes agents 1, 2, 3, and 4.

User 2 selects their name and the sheet is now filtered to show agents 5, 6, 7, and 8. User 2 opens the form and the dropdown includes agents 5, 6, 7, and 8.

Now both users submit their forms. User 1's agent field returns blank while User 2's agent field returns their selection.

Is there any way to get around this validation? I can include the script I'm using to update the form if needed.

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171tcBwXvxo67MguZIowJi53VVk-w0IOuNnujYkx4-qo/edit#gid=0

```
function updateQuestions() {
// call form and connect to the drop-down item
var form = FormApp.openById("1zCelOeCuLDGNCgEILS1VBTAuCR4KPKfXYoNnPmGT2uc");

var namesList = form.getItemById("1310627039").asListItem();

// identify the sheet where data resides to populate the drop-down
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

// grab values in the 1st column of the sheet using 3 to skip header rows
var namesValues = names.getRange(3, 1, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

var agentNames = [];

// convert the array ignoring empty cells
for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)
if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
  agentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

// populate dropdown with array data
namesList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
}
```

Edit: Included sample sheet and code

Comment: *"I can include the script I'm using to update the form if needed."*. Please do. An added example sheet would also help.

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error, it's apparent that your update to the linked Form is causing some form validation logic to trigger, which is then scrubbing your answers from the response.

It's strange because I can't find any record of this in Google's documentation (that is - the Form validation against it's "original" state in Google's backend). I'd say try pulling values from the Sheet using Apps script - but given these are form validation problems you may still run into the same issue.

Probably the best workaround for you would be to create multiple Forms (which can be done programmatically to reduce toil) and then have your Sheet with the dropdown swap out the form URLs rather than this whole "push changes to Forms" setup.